# Firefox console throws "no element found" on HTTP 204 response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, httpresponse, http-status-code-204

Everything actually works, but I can't get rid of this error in the firefox console:

> no element found

I am sending an HTTP request to my api:

```
$http({
    url: API_LOCATION + 'expenses/' + obj.expense.id + '/', 
    method: "DELETE",
}).then(function(response){
    if(response.status === 204) {
        var params = $location.search();
        params['alert-success'] = ALERTS.EXPENSE_DELETED;
        $location.search(params);
    }
    $route.reload();
});
```

and my ([django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/)) api returns an HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT status

Answer (score 11):

This is a Firefox bug which has been <s>recently reopened</s> recently resolved: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=884693